# Mysql query to check username & password using spring boot JPA hibernate repository is not working. what should I do?

Tags: mysql, spring, database, spring-boot, hibernate

```
@Query("select u from users u where u.username = :username and u.password = :password")
Optional<User> login(@Param("username")String username, @Param("password")String password);
```

**I wanna to run the above query but getting error as:**

```
Error creating bean with name 'userController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userService'; 
    nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepository'; 
    nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository' defined in com.ezest.bunge.repository.UserRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; 
    nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.Optional com.ezest.bunge.repository.UserRepository.login(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
```

**Please help me out, I am trying to solve this problem from long time but not getting exact solution**

Comment: please show your User Repository class

Answer (score 0):

Use Entity class name in the query instead of the table name as it is a JPQL query.

```
Query("select u from User ...")
```